# How to better initialise an image: with initWithData method or with imageWithData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, memory-management, uiimage

I am working on the UIImage in iOS and found two methods which does the same work

```
- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data          // (instance method)

+ (UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data  // (class method)
```

Now, if the work done by both are the same then why to have two methods and which is the best way to initialize the image?

Also in class method do we allocate the memory?

Comment: Have you read the docs on these two methods?

Comment: Not so important with ARC, but the first returns a retained object and the second returns an autoreleased object.

Answer (score 2):

They do do the same thing, but the memory management is slightly different. The instance method returns a retained instance and the class method returns an auto-released instance. The difference is historic and doesn't matter when using ARC.

The class method does allocate the required memory for the instance, it's just done internally.

Answer (score 1):

imageWithData is just:

```
+(UIImage *)imageWithData:(NSData *)data
{
    return [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
}
```

Which is exactly what you're going to do if you use `-initWithData` instead, hence why such methods are called "convenience constructors"  Functionally they're not any different, they just save you a little typing.

Pre-arc implementations also include an autorelease call, but the idea is the same, it's just an easy way to create and initialize an object with a little less typing.  Just as `[<class> new]` is a synonym for `[[<class> alloc] init]`.

Answer (score 0):

The both method will work same. But In Memory management instance method returns the image object and it will retain and but by using the class method the object memory get auto release.
If you develop the application without ARC then go for the instance method and you will be responsible to release memory.

In ARC environment no need to release memory independently on a chosen method.